# Stuck with python functions and global variables thinking?

Tags: python, function, global

I'm currently analyzing financial data and for this reason I need to use a certain function, let's say a certain type of moving average, inside the code different times, for different time series and for different time frames too.

To initialize a function I need to declare a global variable, but that variable obviously will keep the value from the previous iteration, like in the following toy example I made, where I would need to add a new random variable to an array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def _foo_append_(x_i,count):               
    global x

    if count==0:
        x = []

    x.append(x_i)

    return x


for i in range(0,10):
    rv_1 = np.round(np.random.normal(10,5),decimals=2)
    rv_2 = np.round(np.random.normal(22,3),decimals=2)

    keep_1 = _foo_append_(x_i=rv_1,count=i)
    keep_2 = _foo_append_(x_i=rv_2,count=i)
```

In this case I get obviously bot keep1 and keep2 of 20 elements, but the both arrays should be composed by 10 elements.

So again it's not about a specific function but how to deal with a need like this one.

**I need a function that everytime is called, creates by itself a new UNIQUE global variable so that this variable will be my output**

- right now my strategy is creating a module where I build several functions that are all equal, such as: `_foo_append_01()`,`_foo_append_02()`,...,`_foo_append_N()` where in each of this functions I will have global variables differently labeled.

This solution is working, but it's very poor way of build a software I think.

Again it's not about a specific code or function, but how to deal with this thinking.

*How should I think and build the best solution for my needs?*
Thank you

Comment: In situations like this, where you think you need a global, you're probably better off with a class, where a given instance stores the "global" as an instance attribute, and it has a method which updates the attribute on each call. Avoids polluting the global namespace, and allows you to have as many such "globals" as you want (instead of being limited to one), one for each instance of the class.

Comment: Can I ask you a toy example of what you suggested to me? Or maybe a link, or what to search on google...

Comment: Do you know how to define and use classes at all? If not, you need to be running through a full Python tutorial. If you do, seriously, it's just prepending the formerly global name with `self.` and defining it in `__init__` (to make it a "defined once at initialization" instance attribute), then modifying it in the methods.

Comment: well I did all the tutorials, but I wouldn't know how to translate this into what I need right now.

Comment: I think what I'm trying to achieve is a function that is built like np.mean(). Infact you can call np.mean() everytime you want with different inputs and it always give an independet and different output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x_arr = list()

    def _foo_append_(self,x_i,count):
        self.x_arr.append(x_i)
        return self.x_arr



for i in range(0,10):
    rv_1 = np.round(np.random.normal(10,5),decimals=2)
    rv_2 = np.round(np.random.normal(22,3),decimals=2)

    if i==0:
        Foo1 = Foo()
        Foo2 = Foo()

    keep_1 = Foo1._foo_append_(x_i=rv_1,count=i)
    keep_2 = Foo2._foo_append_(x_i=rv_2,count=i)
```

still don't like the forced initialization of the process with `if==0:`, I would like to find a way to avoid that calling. But this code is working

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking, but it sounds like you need to create separate lists for the numbers
would this fit what you're in need of?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
globalVar = []

def _foo_append_(x_i,index):               

    if index > len(globalVar):
        globalVar.append([])

    globalVar[index-1].append(x_i)
    
    return globalVar[index-1]


for i in range(0,10):
    rv_1 = np.round(np.random.normal(10,5),decimals=2)
    rv_2 = np.round(np.random.normal(22,3),decimals=2)

    keep_1 = _foo_append_(x_i=rv_1,index=1)
    keep_2 = _foo_append_(x_i=rv_2,index=2)
```

You'd just need to find some way of creating new indexes later, likely just by using something like

```
newIndex = len(globalVar) + 1
```

or something